# A generic way to throw an Exception when mutually exclusive fields are presence using Jackson

Tags: java, jackson, fasterxml

I'm using a Jackson FasterXML version 2.9.0 and stuck with an issue when I need to get rid of the presence of mutually exclusive fields during serialization/deserialization.

Here is the brief example:

```
public class Container {

         private GenericType type;

         private A a;   <-- fields a and b are mutually exclusive
         private B b;   <-- both of them use "type" field as EXTERNAL_PROPERTY to identify the correct Java Type of POJOs
}
```

Is there any way how to throw an exception when such mutually exclusive fields are a presence during serialization/deserializaion?

Solutions with custom Serializers/Deserializers are work fine for me, but I need some more generic functionality that works out of the box, like JAXB - Choice, for instance.

Comment: One `type` property defines `Java Type` for properties `a` and `b`. So `a` and `b` are defined in class in the same way: `private T a` and `private T b`. It also depends whether you want to check wether `JSON`  `payload` is valid or `Java` objects after deserialisation. In case `JSON` you can validate `JSON` against [`JSON Schema`](https://www.baeldung.com/introduction-to-json-schema-in-java). In case `Java` objects you can create constructor with `JsonCreator ` annotation and check in constructor whether two properties are set. Maybe you should not have two properties - just one with aliases.

Comment: @MichałZiober thank you for the answer. Actually I have more  than 2 fields with different types but a single abstract class, I cannot change this due to a business requiements. I have many places where the same approach with &quot;choice&quot; can be integrated, so wondering if I missed something I Jackson documentation, I even thought about creating a custom annotation where all properties will be declared and validate classes with such annotation in runtime